# cURL returns different

Tags: php, ssl, curl

Simple script but does not seem to be posting the fields across correctly on the second server.  The only difference in php info is NSS/3.12.7.0 and NSS/3.12.9.0.  One is on https and the other is not, is there another option that I am missing here?

```
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: "*One is on https and the other is not*": what is? The URL you're trying to access from that script or where you script is hosted?

Comment: they are both ssl when it returns an unexpected result when it works it goes from http to https

Comment: What are "*they*"? What's "*it*" (that goes to https)?

Comment: The server i'm sending from and to are both on ssl and the it is the curl on development http -> https the curl works as expected on the live box the curl goes from https -> https, this is where the curl returns a different result.

Answer (score 1):

Add this it will turn off SSL verification :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: Note that turning off peer verification makes the connection vulnerable to MITM attacks. Generally a bad idea.